# Disabling pop up from ArcGIS Portal after configuring attributes

Tags: arcgis-online, popup

Is there a way to disable configured pop-ups within ArcGIS Online after adjusting  decimal places to 8 for fields Lat and Long in pop ups?

When I disable pop up using remove pop up option decimal place value changes from '8 decimal places' to default '2 decimal places'.

Comment: Lisa, how/where are you displaying those fields?  If you're disabling the popup, I assume it's not in the popup but is it in the map viewers table, the item page data tab or something custom...

Comment: Bjorn, I need to display those fields in both pop up and attribute table. If I am disabling pop up from ArcGIS Portal pop ups will shown with default properties. But I need to change precision to 8 decimal places for fields Lat and Long and also want to disable pop up for feature layers on map loading.